# Все mysql запросы в одном файле php. Правильно ли?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Обычно, я прописываю все необходимые запросы в одном файле - functions.php.
Например, некая форма обрабатывается посредством AJAX. В скрипте в качестве url я всегда указываю functions.php. Уже в этом файле я прописываю условие `if (isset($_POST["login"])) { ... }`.

И так я делаю для любого запроса. Сейчас работаю над сайтом, в котором functions.php состоит из огромного списка условий `if (isset($_POST[...]))` и этот список продолжает расти. Так вот возникает вопрос: всё ли правильно я делаю?

Comment: Ваш файл исполняется на сервере. Если он будет из over 100500 строк, то это может немного замедлить ответ от сервера. Хотя это уже зависит от сервера.

Comment: Скрипты пишутся в первую очередь для человека, как отметил @ВладленВожжаев, сервер проглотит. Вам удобно с таким гигантским файлом работать? Если нет, продумывайте маршрутизацию. Посмотрите концепцию REST.

Comment: Когда-то я тоже сделал так на одном проекте. Все запросы были в одном файле, все было отлично. Проект был не большой, около 8 страниц. Затем я отдал его другому разработчику, проект начал расти. И потом, спустя примерно год я вернулся на проект. Это был **АД**. Они продолжали делать все запросы в одном файле, там было уже 100500 строк кода, каша ужасная, нужную функцию найти почти невозможно. Мораль - это нормально, пока вам удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Так делать не правильно. Почитайте про [Шаблон проектирования
Модель Представление Контроллер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller).
Для серьезного приложения лучше использовать какой нибудь фреймворк, например Yii.
Должно быть несколько контроллеров и в каждом несколько функций. Фреймворк вызывает нужную функцию из нужного контроллера исходя из url запроса.

Comment: Спасибо, уже начал изучать MVC) Но что, если вся работа сайта происходит на одной странице (url вообще не меняется) и все действия обрабатываются через AJAX?

Comment: MVC - не единственный шаблон проектирования. Для всего есть своя область применения, не следует везде пихать MVC просто потому, что Вы знаете что это такое (даже если очень хочется).

Comment: надо менять url для аякс запросов. Например урлы user/login, user/logout, document/view, document/save. Тогда получатся контроллеры UserController и DocumentController. В контроллере UserController функции actionLogin, actionLogout итд. Это пример для фреймворка Yii.

Comment: В Yii2 удобно через rest api делать. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-quick-start